# Cannot load the front end routing in MEAN STACK with Angular 4

Tags: node.js, angular, mean-stack

I am creating an application using MEAN STACK with Angular 4(new to this technology). I am trying to handle thefront end routing i.e. upon use of url http://localhost:3000/admin it should load the admin component and http://localhost:3000/registration its should load the registration component.

App-Routing.modeule.ts

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {RegistrationFormComponent} from './registration-form/registration-form.component';
import {AdminFormComponent} from './admin-form/admin-form.component';


const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: 'registration', component: RegistrationFormComponent},
    {path: 'admin', component: AdminFormComponent},
    {path: '', redirectTo: '/admin', pathMatch: 'full'}
    //{path: '*', redirectTo: '/registration', pathMatch: 'full'}
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {

}
```

server.js

```
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist')));
app.get('/registration', api);
app.get('/admin', api);
app.use('/', api);
```

router.js

```
router.get('/registration', function(req, res){
    //res.send('hello world');
   console.log('registration');
});
```

I have a router.js class also.Routing is working fine in my angular application.However, when using express with angular, I am not how should I handle the front end routing.If it needs to be done through router.js not sure what path should i specify into it.

I am getting error:

> Error: Cannot GET Pagename

Comment: Make sure you have <router-outlet></router-outlet> in the root component and base href set up in index.html. https://angular.io/guide/router

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the static path

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
```

and then

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
});
```

you dnt need to wirte routing in the server side for angular app